# Understanding the result after using Python's clear() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand the result of the code below. Why is the result `None`?

```
 m = {(1,2):1.0, (5,4):0.5, (3,4):0.75}

print(m.clear())
result: **None**
```

But if I write as

```
   m.clear()
    print(m)
   result : **{}**
```

I have other result.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the return value of `m.clear()`, which returns `None`. It returns `None` because the `.clear()` method clears the dictionary *in place*.

By convention, any method on a default Python type that alters the mutable structure in-place, returns `None`. The same applies to `list.sort()` or to `set.add()`, for example.

Your second sample does not print the return value of `m.clear()`. It prints the empty dictionary after you cleared it.

Answer (score 4):

`print(m.clear())` prints the value returned by the call `m.clear()`. `print m` prints the object `m`; clearly two very different things, and so it's unsurprising that they produce different output.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for dictionary types simply says of `clear`:

> Remove all items from the dictionary.

That's what it does. It's not documented as returning anything, while all the documentation for all the methods that *do* return something are explicit about what they return (usually methods that alter a collection only return `None`). So there's no reason to expect it to return anything.